# Proper way to organize images for many users in rackspace cloudfiles for Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rackspace-cloud, express

I have a simple Node.js app. I'll have user profiles and each user can upload several images. The images will be uploaded to Rackspace Cloudfiles.

I am currently using the [Rackit](https://github.com/rossj/rackit) module.

The way it works currently:

I pass Rackit a file, which uploads it to Rackspace Cloudfiles, and returns the CDN url to that image (image name has been hashed by rackit) (url looks something like this):
http://c15142174.r14.ca2.rackcdn.com/Y20h30Jd918aHV3pKROzejdq

Rackit currently saves all the images into ONE container.

**Here are my questions:**
1) Should I save each user's images into a separate container (for privacy, security, and to make sure one user can't erase another users)?

2) Would it be sufficient to simply store the url ref above in a database and reference it that way in the future? Can I count on this url not changing?

3) Would it make more sense to prefix a user's image with a username or hash that ties the images to a given user?

What's the best practice approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was referred to this great article that really answered my questions very well:
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/content/best-practices-using-cloud-files

To sum up the article for my use case:

1) **Use multiple containers**. Having lots of images in one container slows you down, especially since there's a throttle on how frequently you can write to the same container. This could be especially problematic if 2 users are simultaneously trying to upload images to the same container. Hence a different container for each user makes sense here.

2) **You can use pseudo folders** for organization if needed. You can name your image (it's an object in rackspace cloud) "/user123/ducks/duck_small.jpg". In this scenario the name of the image is that entire string (including the slashes).

3) **Store references to the images in your database**. Accessing cloudfiles to list the contents of the container would be MUCH slower than simply getting the cdn url for the image from your database.

Comment: FYI - Rackspace Cloudfiles now has an absolute limit of 500,000 containers per account.